Finding the minimum of the sum of Chebyshev distances
Given the vectors $(x_1, \dots, x_n)$ with $x_i = (x_{11}, \dots, x_{ik})$,  I am trying to minimize the following function
$$ s(a) = \sum_{i=1}^n \max_{j\in\{1, \dots, k\}} |a_j - x_{ij}|$$
with regards to $a$. This is the sum of Chebyshev distances from the point $a$ to all vectors $(x_1, \dots, x_n)$. I have tried finding the derivative regarding an $a_m$, but this results in piecewise derivatives with no variables left, so I cannot continue from there. Is there a derivative defined for this function?

Rather than derivative, this problem can be converted to a linear programming problem.
The LP is as follows:
$$\min_{p, a} \sum_{i=1}^n p_i$$
subject to $$p_i \ge a_j-x_{ij}, \forall i \in \{1, \ldots, n\},\forall j \in \{1,\ldots, k\}$$
$$p_i \ge x_{ij}-a_j, \forall i \in \{1, \ldots, n\},\forall j \in \{1,\ldots, k\}$$
This can be solved via a linear programming algorithm such as the simplex algorithm.

Thanks! Am I correct in assuming that we can not give a general expression for the value of $a$ minimizing the sum? As in, we need the values of $(x_1, \dots, x_n)$ to solve the LP, right?

$a$ should be a function of $x$.

But can we find a general expression for a in terms of x?

I can't see a quick way for now.
